# Extracting one-hot vector from text

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, vector, nlp

In `pandas` or `numpy`, I can do the following to get one-hot vectors:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = [0,2,1,4,3]
>>> pd.get_dummies(x).values
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])

>>> np.eye(len(set(x)))[x]
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

From text, with `gensim`, I can do:

```
>>> from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
>>> sent1 = 'this is a foo bar sentence .'.split()
>>> sent2 = 'this is another foo bar sentence .'.split()
>>> texts = [sent1, sent2]
>>> vocab = Dictionary(texts)
>>> [[vocab.token2id[word] for word in sent] for sent in texts]
[[3, 4, 0, 6, 1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 7, 6, 1, 2, 5]]
```

Then I'll have to do the same `pd.get_dummies` or `np.eyes` to get the one-hot vector but I get an error where there's one dimension missing from my one-hot vector I have 8 unique words but the one-hot vector lengths are only 7:

```
>>> [pd.get_dummies(sent).values for sent in texts_idx]
[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])]
```

It seems like it's doing one-hot vector individually as it iterates through each sentence, instead of using the global vocabulary.

Using `np.eye`, I do get the right vectors:

```
>>> [np.eye(len(vocab))[sent] for sent in texts_idx]
[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])]
```

Also, currently, I have to do several things from using `gensim.corpora.Dictionary` to converting the words to their ids then getting the one-hot vector.

**Are there other ways to achieve the same one-hot vector from texts?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various packages that will do all the steps in a single function such as http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html.

Alternatively, if you have your vocabulary and text indexes for each sentence already, you can create a one-hot encoding by preallocating and using smart indexing. In the following text_idx is a list of integers and vocab is a list relating integers indexes to words.

```
import numpy as np
vocab_size = len(vocab)
text_length = len(text_idx)
one_hot = np.zeros(([vocab_size, text_length])
one_hot[text_idx, np.arange(text_length)] = 1
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What is d here?

Comment: Sorry, looking back at this I think there is a typo. and d and sent are the same thing, while text_idx is a list of integers corresponding to the one_hot encodings. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

to create one_hot_vector, you need to create unique vocabulary from text

```
vocab=set(vocab)
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(vocab)
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
doc = "dog"
index=vocab.index(doc)
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
one_hot_encoder=one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)[index]
```

Answer (score -1):

The 7th value is the "."(Dot) in your sentences separated by a " "(space) and **split()** counts it as a **word** !!